# How to create the smallest file possible that contains a SHA256 hash?

Tags: powershell, hash, powershell-2.0, line-breaks, sha256

I'm using Powershell 2.0.

I have a variable that contains a single SHA256 hash value (which corresponds to the hash of a file, here `$filename`):

```
$filename = "C:\aaa\aaa.exe"
$sha256Value = ... # The hash for $filename
```

I want to save that value to a file. Here the first solution I tried:

```
$sha256Value | Out-File -FilePath ($filename + ".sha256")
```

The size of the file (not on disk) is 134 bytes. With this command, it generates a line break in the .sha256 files.

The second solution I tried:

```
[IO.File]::AppendAllText(($filename + ".sha256"),$sha256Value,[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

With the second option, the file size (not on disk) is 67 bytes and it also doesn't contain a line break.

Also just by removing the UTF8 encoding, I can get the file size down to 64 bytes.

Is there any other solution that would decrease the file size? Also, is it possible to get the same file size for the first solution (i.e. with Out-File)?

Comment: `out-file` has an encoding parameter: `Out-File -FilePath ($filename + ".sha256") -encoding UTF8`

Comment: @Lee, It does get the file size down to 69 bytes. However, there is still a line break.

Comment: Most of the PowerShell cmdlets like `Set-Content` and `Out-File` will add the line break.

Comment: Do you need file to be in human-readable format (can be opened in text-editor to see hash digits)?

Comment: @Imortist, the file doesn't have to be human-readable. So I would accept a solution that's is not human-readable if it provides the smallest file.

Comment: Then @Lee suggested a good one. You may not need this part "[text.encoding]::utf8.getbytes($sha256Value)" if your $sha256Value is byte array already

Answer (score 2):

You can write the bytes directly:

```
[text.encoding]::utf8.getbytes($sha256Value) | set-content ($filename + ".sha256") -encoding byte
```